# Shouldn't number of candidates found be zero when no search parameters are specified?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

If I login to the careers site as an employer, then on the search page de-select everything -- so no tags, no location, no type or students -- why doesn't the count of candidates found go to zero?

It seems like the semantics for the Type checkboxes should be "someone with one or more of the following attributes".  But with no attributes checked and a non-zero result count, does that mean many candidates don't have any boxes checked in their profiles?  What's happening is not obvious or intuitive.

Comment: funny - I'd expect that if you did *NOT* filter, you'd get everyone

Comment: except you aren't applying filters (negatives)--the way the selection system is setup, you're asking for matches (positives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up - this will be in the next deployment.